# How is roll control achieved for the space ship two?

Tags: aircraft-design, control-surfaces, roll, scaled-composites

When looking at [scaled composite 339 space ship two](https://www.airliners.net/search?aircraft=43393) I fail to see control surfaces on the [trailing edge of the wing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0WQ0KjScOU). For me, it seems that the only moving surface on the wing is the feathering mechanism and that control surfaces are all located on the tail.

My question is: when not in space, how is roll control achieved? does it use horizontal stabilizer in an asymmetric way? Is there a control surface I fail to see?

Comment: There is *never* any *control* surface on the *leading* edge of the wing. Only high-lift devices are on the leading edge (slats). The ailerons are normally on the outboard parts of the wing *trailing* edge, but the only reason they are there is that it is furthest from the longitudinal axis. Now what is furthest from the longitudinal axis here…?

Comment: @JanHudec updated

Comment: There seems to be some sort of reaction control system integrated into the wing, details seem sparse. see: http://www.parabolicarc.com/2019/08/14/virgin-galactic-completes-wing-for-third-spaceshiptwo/

Comment: @NileRiver, the next sentence fragment is the relevant though: “elevon flight controls”.

Comment: @Manu H -- At 2:09 in the video (see https://youtu.be/X0WQ0KjScOU?t=129 ) I see no shortage of control surfaces.  Are you familiar with elevons?

Comment: @quietflyer are you referring to the surfaces outside the rudders? For me it looks more like a classic tail than a delta wing, and the wing itself is more inside the rudders. Yet I fail to see any control surface movement in your video (given the airspeed, movement should be small), thus I cannot state the elevator is used for roll control.